# SpriteKit rotation confusion

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to understand, in a *general* way, how to address the flipping that occurs when using atan/atan2 and SK's zRotation.

My Swift code catches the mouseDown and then calculates the angle between the current location and the click using this little function:

```
func angleBetweenPointOne(PointOne: CGPoint, andPointTwo PointTwo: CGPoint) -> Double {
    let xdiff = CDouble(PointTwo.x - PointOne.x)
    let ydiff = CDouble(PointTwo.y - PointOne.y)
    let rad = atan2(ydiff, xdiff)
    return rad - 1.5707963268       // convert from atan's right-pointing zero to CG's up-pointing zero
}
```

Now I do this:

```
let action = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(angle), duration:0.2)
PlayerSprite.runAction(action)
```

Most of the time it works fine, the sprite cleanly rotates to the new angle. This works for most points you might click/touch. However, if the clicks cross the -ve Y axis - i.e. the click was just below the sprite and the next is just above, the angle is not a small one but 360 minus the angle. So the sprite rotates the long way.

I'm trying to understand how to address this so I don't keep making the same mistake over and over.

Comment: What does `CG's up-pointing zero` mean? You are calculating the correct angle between the two points without the pi/2.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Rotating a sprite to the touch location?

Comment: "Up pointing zero" means that SK's zero rotation is "up". atan2's zero rotation is "right". So they are off by 90 degrees, or -1.57... rads.

Comment: @Stephan - yes, precisely. Let's say you click at the relative location +5x +10Y, sprite rotates +30 degrees. Now click at +25X -15Y - works great rotates another 30 degrees. or so. Now click -75X -10Y, another 90 degrees maybe, now it's pointed almost to the left. Now click -80X, +10Y, *sprite rotates through 350 degrees counter-clockwise*.

Comment: You're calculating the angle correctly (for this purpose. I can explain more if you want). What it sounds like from your comments (you should edit the question with this info too) is that the problem isn't that the node ends up pointing the wrong way, but that it sometimes takes the long way around. This tells me that the problem isn't in the code you've posted, but rather the code you use to actually perform the rotation.

Comment: @AndrewKnoll Yes Andrew, that is it exactly. I will edit the question to reflect the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the line

```
let action = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(angle), duration:0.2)
```

with

```
let action = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(angle), duration:0.2, shortestUnitArc:true)
```

What's happening is that when the clicks cross the negative-X axis, the angle returned from atan2() changes from "something close to `π`" to "something close to `-π`," or vice versa. You've offset this by a quarter turn, so it shows up on the negative-Y axis instead. Both `π` and `-π` yield the same rotation of the sprite, but when the action calculates the transition between them, it sees a difference of `2π`, and inserts intermediary points appropriately.

The `shortestUnitArc` parameter allows you to require a check to see if the other way is shorter, and if so, rotate that way.

Comment: That is both a working solution, as well as the "always will work" solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz the `rotateToAngle` also has duration, how you are managing it? Means rotating will take different times for different angles, how you are calculating this time?

Comment: I left it at 0.2, which made it turn faster for further rotation - but that's what I wanted in my case.